# How to find solutions when variables are used for digits in a number?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to know what the formulas are for being able to solve problems where they ask about specific digits in a number instead of the whole number.

For example I was trying to find solutions to AB/CA = B/C. So far by manually trying the combinations of a lot of digits I was able to get A=6, B=4, C=1.  So 64/16 = 4/1.

Is that the only way to solve something like this or is there a formula that I can use or a special technique?  I've also seen similar problems about calculating the age between parents and children by asking about digits in reverse order of their age, so I'm trying to find a general way of solving these kinds of problems instead of just the solution to this particular one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand the question. If a number is formatted $AB$, then you can expand it using place value. Mathematically, $AB$ is $10A + B$.

In your question, you would have,

$$\frac{10A + B}{10C + A} = \frac{B}{C} \Longrightarrow 10AC + BC = 10BC + AB$$

Thus,

$$10AC = 9BC + AB$$

where $A, B, C \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now there are a number of ways to attack the problem.

$$A = \frac{9BC}{10C - B}$$

Since $A$ is integral, then $10C - B$ must divide $9BC$. We can easily work through cases for $C$. If $C = 1$, then $\frac{9B}{10 - B}$ must be integral. We see that $B = 1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9$ are all solutions. However, we want $0 < A < 9$, and so $B = 7, 8, 9$ aren't valid.

We can go through cases to find all the solutions.

Comment: Oh wow, that's so smart :) so you are saying that you have to solve (10A+B)/(10C+A) = B/C.  And then just treat it like a regular algebra?

Comment: Yeah, you would still have some casework to do, but that's generally a good approach to these problems

Comment: From simplifying it I got 10AC = 9BC +AB.  But how do I figure out what the integers are for that without trying all the combinations?

Comment: I edited the answer. There are a lot of solutions to this general problem. Do you have some general guidelines? Do you know if one number is larger than another?

Comment: By integral do you mean integer?  There aren't any guidelines because I made up the problem. But it looks like you still have to try everything though.

Comment: B = 10AC/(9C+A)  if we substitute that into your formula for A does that help anything?

Comment: I do. And oh, gotcha. Yeah, you'll still have to divide along cases for one variable, but it will make it faster and more systematic. Some problems may also simplify more nicely than this one.

Comment: If you substitute that and simplify, I believe it should return A = A

Comment: Oh ok, that isn't any good.  Thanks for your help nick.  I guess there isn't really a nice solution like I hoped.  But your answer is probably as good as it will get. Thanks :) +1

Comment: Actually I think it does make it faster because like you wrote you can put a cutoff point where A becomes > 9. So you don't have to test anything past 7 for B.